# Help with a slight issue in reading in a text file using the '<' redirection operator in command line? C

Tags: c, file, text, redirect, stdin

I've searched high and low, but can not find the answer to what I would've thought to be a rather simple question. I'm rather new to C, and due to the restrictions placed on me during this project I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do this.

I am trying to read in text from a text file, and store that data in an array. Simple enough. HOWEVER, I'm forced to do so by using the command line operator '<' and to redirect the stdin to the text file.

The only way I can seem to figure out how to properly open a file and perform the subsequent operations is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>  


FILE *fr;           

main()

{

   fr = fopen ("mytext.txt", "r");  /* open the file for reading */
```

The problem with that is that I can't seem to get the first parameter of fopen() to be the filename provided by the stdin '<'. It only works if I explicitly type a string in for the parameter. For example, if I were to run

```
myprog.o < mytxt.txt
```

how could I pass the name of the text file provided by that stdin redirection to the fopen function? Or is there a different/better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's ... stdin. You read from stdin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read from `stdin` instead of trying to open the file directly.

This is because of how redirection works - think of it a bit like this:

1. The file is opened (for purposes of demonstration, let's say `fopen` is used for this).
2. The existing `stdin` is closed. It no longer refers to a terminal or similar construct.
3. `stdin` is replaced with the open file in step 1.
4. Any reads from `stdin` now work directly from the input file.

By using input redirection you can permit your user to either redirect a file or directly type content into your program.

As for your actual problem, you might be better off passing the filename as an argument to your program. You would use `argv` and call your program like so:

```
myprog.o mytxt.txt
```

In this case, `argv[1]` will be `mytxt.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard `FILE*` handle declared within `<stdio.h>` that points to the standard input for the executing process. Such file handle is called `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

A C program never sees the redirection because it is handled by the shell. The C program should look at `argc` and read from stdin if no args are given or from the given files otherwise.

Comment: This isn't about real-world conventions; it's about homework assignment requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If all you ever want this program to do is read from standard input, then you don't need to open any files.  The OS and C libraries will handle opening and closing the file for you.

So to read a file in from standard input, and write it back out, try something as simple as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    int ch = getchar();
    while ( ch != EOF ) {
        putchar( ch );
        ch = getchar();
    }
}
```

As you can see, no opening or closing of files.  `putchar` and `getchar` write to stdin and stdout relatively.

If you want to be more explicit, you can use the predefined file handles.

```
int ch = fgetc( stdin );
while ( ch != EOF ) {
    fputc( ch, stdout );
    ch = fgetc( stdin );
}
```

You should look up `printf()` and `fprintf()`, `scanf()` and `fscanf()`, and all the other wonderful stdio functions.